# How can you return good data from inside a function if the function breaks?

Tags: python, function, error-handling

I am gathering data from a web api (using python) and I am using a loop to go through thousands of calls to the api.  The function was running fine but my computer went to sleep and the internet connection was lost.  I am storing the data as a list of dictionarys while calling the api. My question is this: When the function failed, since my list was inside the function I can't even get the several hundred successful calls it made before it failed.  How can I add error handling or some other method so that if it fails at some point, say after 500 calls, I can still get 499 pieces of data?

If I had run the code without putting it into a function, my list would still be viable up to the point the code broke, but I felt like putting it into a function was "more correct"

```
#this is how the function is set up in pseudo-code:
def api_call(x):
    my_info = []
    for i in x:
        dictionary = {}
        url=f'http://www.api.com/{x}'
        dictionary['data'] = json['data']
        my_info.append(dictionary)
    return my_info

another_variable = api_call(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap it in a try/except/finally block. The finally is always executed before leaving the try statement. Explanation of what the finally block does is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions).

```
def api_call(x):
    my_info = []
    try:
        for i in x:
            dictionary = {}
            url=f'http://www.api.com/{x}'
            dictionary['data'] = json['data']
            my_info.append(dictionary)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Oopsie')  # Can log the error here if you need to 
    finally:
        return my_info

another_variable = api_call(x)
```